# How do I trigger a client reconnect with OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, udp, vpn-client

I am running multiple replicas of OpenVPN server (on a Kubernetes cluster) and have configured clients to reconnect should a server instance go down (with `keepalive 10 60`) which works fairly well.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to configure OpenVPN to trigger a client reconnect if a server shuts down on purpose (for example when performing a rolling update) to avoid the client hanging for 60 seconds.

Comment: Not with built-in OpenVPN commands, I believe. That's what `keepalive`/ `ping` and `ping-restart` are for.

Comment: Ah that's shame, I feel like that should be a feature using some ICMP unreachable message

Comment: You can always write your own feature :). But aren't these 3 options enough if you set a low threshold?

Comment: not really, I would want the timeout to be longer if the server doesn't tell me it has stopped, but immediate if the server does - the `–explicit-exit-notify [n]` option for OpenVPN 2.4 did the trick. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [reference manual for OpenVPN 2.4](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/):

> `–explicit-exit-notify [n]`: In UDP server mode, send RESTART control channel command to connected clients.

Comment: Oh nice, didn't know that. I have a use for this myself, ty! This has been implemented since about forever, I see....

Comment: It has in client mode afaik, but 2.4 introduced this option in server mode too